# Java - Json File Parser issue

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am trying to read two objects in Json file using Java JSONParser but I am getting a below issue while parsing a Json file. I have provided Java code and Json file content for your reference.

**Issue:**

```
Unexpected token LEFT BRACE({) at position 286.
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
```

**Java Code:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        JSONParser  parser = new JSONParser();
         JSONObject a = null;
         Connection con = null;
         Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\mhq175\\workspace2\\JCucumber\\JSON_FILES\\Datafile.json"));
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONObject structure = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("MessageContext");
            JSONObject structure_2 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("MessageContext1");
            con = postconn.getConnection();
            String entireFileText = "INSERT INTO Events"
                       + " VALUES ('"+ structure + "','"+ structure_2 + "');";
            System.out.println(entireFileText); 
            stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
             stmt.executeUpdate(entireFileText);
    }   catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Json File:**

```
{
    "MessageContext": {
        "field1": "VALUE1",
        "field2": "VALUE2",
        "field3": "VALUE3",
        "field4": "VALUE4",
        "field5": "VALUE5"
    },
    "MessageContext1": {
        "field1": "VALUE1",
        "field2": "VALUE2",
        "field3": "VALUE3",
        "field4": "VALUE4",
        "field5": "VALUE5"
    }
}{
    "MessageContext": {
        "field1": "VALUE1",
        "field2": "VALUE2",
        "field3": "VALUE3",
        "field4": "VALUE4",
        "field5": "VALUE5"
    },
    "MessageContext1": {
        "field1": "VALUE1",
        "field2": "VALUE2",
        "field3": "VALUE3",
        "field4": "VALUE4",
        "field5": "VALUE5"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you validate your JSON with any online tools ? `}{` is not correct. I like jsonlint

Comment: Your json file is not valid: it contains 2 json objects after each other.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you are sending in not correct. It consist of 2 JSON object one after another which is illegal. Either you have to add both object in JSONArray, get individual object from array and manipulate it. 
Or you can split Json string at "}{" and then convert it to json object for further calculation.

P.S. i know the second approach is dirty but this could make make someone day.

Comment: If you split at `}{`, it still would be invalid unless you added those characters back

Comment: That is something which is quite understood. My answer is just to give directions

Comment: Not everyone understands JSON format (as evident by the question), so I thought I would explicitly say that